# Cells for TableView are not showing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, firebase

I am trying to program a social media app and I want the posts to appear in the cells. The only things in the cell are a label for the post and a label for the topic. When I run the code there are no errors but the cells are not showing in the table. I cannot seem to figure out the problem. Thank you for your guys help.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseAuth
import SwiftKeychainWrapper

class FeedVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,     UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var postBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

var posts = [Post]()
var post: Post!
var userName: String!

var refPosts: DatabaseReference!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    //getting a reference to the node posts
    refPosts = Database.database().reference().child("posts")

    //observing the data changes
    refPosts.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        //if the reference have some values
        if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {

            //clearing the list
            self.posts.removeAll()

            //iterating through all the values
            for data in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                //getting values
                let postObject = data.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                let id = postObject?["id"]
                let thought = postObject?["thought"]
                let likes = postObject?["likes"]

                //creating artist object with model and fetched values
                let post = Post(_id: id as! String, _thought: thought as! String?, _likes: likes as! Int?)
                //appending it to list
                self.posts.append(post)
            }

            //reloading the tableview
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    })


    /*refPosts.observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
        if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] { //all objects in snapshot

            self.posts.removeAll()

            for data in snapshot {
                print(data)
                if let postDict = data.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{
                    let key = data.key
                    let post = Post(postKey: key, postData: postDict)
                    self.posts.append(post)
                }
            }
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })*/

}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let post = posts[indexPath.row]
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell") as? PostCell{
        cell.configCell(post: post)
        return cell
    }else{
        return PostCell()
    }
}

func PostToFirebase(imgUrl: String){
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let data = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{
        //if let snap = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
            let data = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

            let username = data["username"]

            let post: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [
                "username": username as AnyObject,
                "likes": 0 as AnyObject
            ]
            let firebasePost = Database.database().reference().child("posts").childByAutoId()
            firebasePost.setValue(post)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    })
}

@IBAction func postImageTapped(_ sender: AnyObject){//leads to text field box -> What are you thinking?
    //present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    //performSegue(withIdentifier: "UploadPage", sender: nil)
}

@IBAction func SignOut (_ sender: AnyObject){

    try! Auth.auth().signOut()

    KeychainWrapper.standard.removeObject(forKey: "uid")

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Comment: It could be a design error. Basically never optional downcast a cell in `dequeueReusableCell`. Use the other API `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:` and force unwrap the cell `as! PostCell`. If everything is hooked up correctly the code must not crash in this line. That's one of the very few cases where optional downcast is nonsensical.

Comment: like this?  `if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for as! PostCell){`

Comment: No, `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell", for: indexPath) as! PostCell`. No leading `if`, no trailing `{`. If you get a crash, there is an issue in Interface Builder

Comment: ok it crashed. What do I do to fix it so it doesn't crash

Comment: In IB is the cell  identifier set correctly? Is the class of the custom cell set to `PostCell`?

Comment: What does IB stand for? Sorry I am kinda new to swift

Comment: (**I**)nterface (**B**)uilder

Comment: How do I know if the cell identifier is set correctly?

Comment: Select the cell and check I in the Identity Inspector (⌥⌘3). Please read something about the basics to implement a custom cell in a table view

Comment: I followed a tutorial and did exactly what they did and that's why I am confused why it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @vadian mentioned in the comments, forcing the cast would be fine in this scenario considering you have everything setup correctly. Try adding the print statements I have below so you can see in more detail what it happening with the cells.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let post = posts[indexPath.row]
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell") as? PostCell {
        print("dequeueing cell")
        cell.configCell(post: post)
        return cell
    }else{
        print("initialising cell")
        return PostCell()
    }
}
```

The solution involves using the newer dequeue method that takes an index path and forcing the cast.

```
let post = posts[indexPath.row]
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell", for: indexPath) as! PostCell

cell.configCell(post: post)

return cell
```

Comment: I saw the comments that it printed. It just kept printing "initialising cell"

Comment: Right so have established that the dequeued cell is either nil or cannot be casted to a `PostCell`.

Comment: So how do I fix this?

Comment: I already swapped your code in and it caused crashed the app.

Comment: Okay well if your cells are in the storyboard, then they are prototype cells and should have a Cell Identifier. You can add the cell identifier by going to the storyboard, selecting the cell and then on the right hand side bar, look for the Cell Identifier property and enter 'PostCell'.

Comment: Now this line `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell", for: indexPath) as! PostCell` technically shouldn't crash. However, if it does please show us the error you're getting.